# How can I stretch the edge colors of elements in an image with alpha channel?

Tags: image, colors, imagemagick, border, edge-detection

I have an PNG with an alpha channel. First I want to find all elements in the png, then I want to stretch the last color on the border about 5 to 10 pixels out

The stretching has to be in all directions from the center of each object on the image (like triangle, rectangle...)

It is important that I keep the color of each pixel on the edge

Is this possible? Goal is in the future to automate the process with ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a play with distort and it is probably the way to go but needs more investigation. I was working on a smaller image and the code is basically a proof of concept.

I think edge is the key option and with this example I reduced the size of the resized image all round by 20px in the distort.
I do not know how you would get the angled edges though.I know you do not want to distort the original but it may give you some ideas as to how to get the result you want.

```
convert "1.png" -trim -matte -virtual-pixel edge -mattecolor none -interpolate Spline +distort BilinearForward "0,0 20,20 400,0 380,20 400,95 380,55 0,95  20,55" -trim +repage "result.png"
```

[image: Result of the code]

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is going on at the edges of your image, but this should get you started...

First, I trim off any transparent edges (with `-trim`) so we get to the actual pattern you seek to extend. Then clone the image and dispose of everything except the top row of pixels (with `-crop`). Then scale that row up till it is 800 pixels tall. Then exchange the tall top row with the original image in the processing order (using `+swap`) and append the original image below the height-extended top row.

```
convert cells.png -trim +repage \( +clone -crop x1+0+0 -scale x800! \) +swap -append result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks, already looks very good. The final image look like something like this (made in PS). 

http://kohlhas-3d.de/3.jpg

Is it possible to stretch automaticly all edges out, like you done it with the first row? I mean for all triangels.
Many thanks!

Comment: Just rotate the triangle till the next side is at the top and repeat the procedure above - twice.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Unfortunately the sides of the triangle are not straight but curved. 
We have to make a workflow, that solves the problem with the image including 8 triangels and one rectangle. Is there a chance?

Comment: Now I am sure I did something like this by mistake once but can not remember how. I think it may have been with a distort.

Comment: Thank you! We will try it with distort, maybe this will be the right way.